# Can I create a class from an object?

Tags: java, class, object, javafx

for example, I use 
`Rectangle pinkSquare = FXMLLoader.load(Paths.get("layout", "Pink square.fxml").toUri().toURL())` 
created a Rectangle object. Can I make a class out of `pinkSquare` object, say `PinkSquare` and use it freely for create more objects?

I know I can use FXMLLoader to do this again, but can I create a class from `pinkSquare` anyway?

Comment: `instance.getClass()`

Comment: What would you expect this classes functionality to be?

Comment: @Michael I'm not trying to get the 'Rectangle' class, I wanna keep the state information of 'pinkSquare' and save it as a subclass of 'Rectangle'

Comment: @fabian keep `pinkSquare`'s state and save it as a subclass of `Rectangle`

Comment: @Chester You can't create classes at runtime*. You create instances of classes at runtime. (*well, technically you can, but you shouldn't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built in way to do that but you could extend `Rectangle` class and create a method that returns a deep copy of it. However, that's just unnecessary work when you could just use FXMLLoader again, unless there's some significant performance gain from deep copying compared to loading the FXML, but I highly doubt that's the case.